# When I create standard data file in Desfire EV1 card, I get 0x0E error

Tags: nfc, rfid, mifare

- I'm using Desfire EV1 8K card. I create 10 applications inside it and create multiple files in that applications successfully.
- When I try to create first file of size 250 bytes in last application, it gives error 0x0E. But if I count total file sizes of previously created files, it's 6100 bytes.
- It means I have still 2092 (=8192(8KB)-6100) bytes to use for file. Please guide where I'm wrong.
- APDU command: CD 00 03 1111 FA0000
- Response: 0x0E (OUT_OF_EEPROM_ERROR)

Answer (score 1):

Did you consider in your calculation that creating applications creates some overhead, e.g. for the file structure, but mainly for the 14 keys per application?

Comment: Hi @ErikM, Thank you response! Do you mean if my one application has 5 AES keys, it will occupy 80 bytes (16 bytes key * 5) in Desfire card??

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer. If I check the FreeMemory of the card, I get the 0 bytes.
The misunderstanding is, I was only calculating file sizes, but if I calculate the key bytes per application, the card is full with no memory left inside.